Get a list of Onfido document report result in java
I am trying to find the best way to get a list of all the non-"clear" results from an Onfido document report.
Onfido provides a java API, that is generated by open-api. The generated code sadly is 100% typed for object that follow a similar structure. The nested breakdown, with result and other potential breakdown all have their own type exmaple DocumentBreakdownDataValidation, DocumentBreakdownDataValidationBreakdown, ...
A snippet of the json structure:
{
  "check_id": "3caa70ef-6ac8-489b-aa60-0907fe2bb22c",
  "name": "document",
  "properties": {
    "first_name": "JOHN",
    "last_name": "DOE",
    "issuing_country": "BE"
  },
  "result": "consider",
  "status": "complete",
  "sub_result": "caution",
  "breakdown": {
    "data_comparison": {
      "result": "clear",
      "breakdown": {
        "date_of_expiry": {
          "result": null,
          "properties": {}
        },
        "issuing_country": {
          "result": null,
          "properties": {}
        }
      }
    },
    "compromised_document": {
      "result": "clear"
    },
    "data_consistency": {
      "result": "clear",
      "breakdown": {
        "last_name": {
          "result": "clear",
          "properties": {}
        },
        "first_name": {
          "result": "clear",
          "properties": {}
        },
      }
    },
    "image_integrity": {
      "result": "consider",
      "breakdown": {
        "conclusive_document_quality": {
          "result": "consider",
          "properties": {
            "missing_back": "clear",
            "digital_document": "clear",
            "abnormal_document_features": "consider"
          }
        },
        "supported_document": {
          "result": "clear",
          "properties": {}
        },
        "image_quality": {
          "result": "clear",
          "properties": {}
        },
        "colour_picture": {
          "result": "clear",
          "properties": {}
        }
      }
    },
    "visual_authenticity": {
      "result": "clear",
      "breakdown": {
        "other": {
          "result": "clear",
          "properties": {}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Using just the onfido API I have a java class with over 300 lines of code like this:
    DocumentBreakdown breakdown = documentReport.getBreakdown();
    DocumentBreakdownDataValidation dataValidation = breakdown.getDataValidation();
    DocumentBreakdownDataValidationBreakdown dataValidationbBreakdown = dataValidation.getBreakdown();
    dataValidationbBreakdown.getBarcode().getResult();
    dataValidationbBreakdown.getGender().getResult();

I am stuck in finding a better approach. Either forking and modifying the Onfido openAPI schema and generating a different library with generics or serialising and deserialising the object into another object type that I control with an interface that I can use in a recursive method. The last solution seems strange as the data is send as JSON -> parsed by Onfido-api -> back to json -> deserialise as my object.
The result of the method would be to have a list of all the errors like:
["abnormal_document_features"]

I need this list so I can inform my front-end to show the user and inform them to take a better picture or use a different document, ...
I looked at the API and it doesn't seem like this functionality exist, which I find a bit strange as I think everyone using Onfido and would like to give the user some information about why a check failed has to parse this entire document.
https://documentation.onfido.com/api/
